# What is the range of the function $f(x)=\log x+\sin x $?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've been thinking about this problem for some time now and I initially thought that the range was $\mathbb R$ . I arrived at that conclusion because in a similar problem we had to find the range of $g(x)=2x^3-|x|+\dfrac{5x}{1+x^2}$ and it turned out to be $\mathbb R$.

I had sort of convinced myself that the sum of a bounded function and a function that takes all real values must be a function that takes all real values but apparently that is not true after all. So how do we find the range of $f(x)$?

Comment: $sinx$ is a bounded function but $logx $ can vary from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ however slow may that be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement about the sum of a bounded and a surjective function ends up being true if you restrict yourself to **continuous** functions with doman an interval.  The intermediate value theorem can be phrased as saying that the image of an interval under a continuous map is an interval.  Therefore, any continuous function with an image that is unbounded from above and below has all of $\Bbb R$ in its image.  This property will be unchanged by adding a bounded function.

Since $\log x$ has image $\Bbb R$ on $(0, \infty)$, the same is true of $\log x + \sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

$\log x$ is a strictly increasing function with range $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and domain of $(0,+\infty)$ if we consider the real valued logarithm. So, since we have addition of an unbounded function on $\Bbb{R}$ with a function oscillating in $[-1,1]$ , the resultant $f(x)$ is also unbounded on $\Bbb{R}$.